# Mysql SUM inside a CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a query that is something like this:

```
select 
    table1.column1, 
    table1.column2,
    ...,
    case when foo.id is null then 'N/A' else sum(foo.points) end as score -- same result using ifnull()
from 
    table1 inner join table2 on ...
    left join foo on ...
group by ...
```

Since I do a `LEFT JOIN` on `foo`, there is a chance that there is no match. In that case, I want the `score` to show as `'N/A'` instead of `NULL` or `0`. But when I do the above query, I get `blob` for the `score` column for all rows.

Comment: You can use `coalesce` as `coalesce(sum(foo.points),0)`

Comment: Is foo.id part of your GROUP BY clause?

Comment: foo.id is not part of my group by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have different data types in the results in the case it will return a value with the data type `blob` if it can't find a common type.

Try casting the sum to a char:

```
case when foo.id is null then 'N/A' else cast(sum(foo.points) as char) end as score
```

Comment: This worked after I changed it to char instead of varchar, and having the "as char" inside the cast(). Thanks.

Comment: @Rickkwa: Corrected the syntax. I was looking at another answer for the `cast` syntax in MySQL, but obviously I should have gone directly to the documentation.

Comment: The varchar also needs to be changed since it isn't a supported type for cast, as mentioned here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: @Rickkwa: Right, I thought that he `cast` supported most types, like for example SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping, you should really put your sum around the case, like:

`sum(case when foo.id is null then 0 else foo.points)`

..as otherwise you are summing just the row value (meaning only one value).

Also, a column should only have one data type, so either number or text, which is why you might be seeing this issue since you are trying to display either a number or text in the same column.

If you really want N/A, you can try converting the number to text, and then using the coalesce function to handle nulls, however I would need to see your data to say the best way to write your above query.  If you can create an SQL fiddle, I would be more than happy to take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

SUM up the the results of the CASE..WHEN.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN foo.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE foo.points) END AS score
```

You can display the default value in the frontend application (n/a) when the score field is null (or equals to 0).

The score will be NULL when there all rows has null in foo.id.